# How can I convince the public that the evidence I have gathered is legitimate?

Tags: government, secret-society, conspiracy

I have uncovered evidence of an international organization called the scp foundation that is supported and funded by various governments around the world. This organization investigates the paranormal and secures items or creatures that are considered supernatural in nature in order to protect the world.  However, they routinely tests on these items using human subjects called D-class prisoners . These individuals are  taken from various countries and are often death row convicts, but also include other undesirables. These test subjects are experimented on and forced to participate in dangerous tests to determine what these items can do. This is against the laws of universal rights that the United Nations has established, and it is our duty as citizens to expose this evil.

I have documents written by staff documenting the experiments, voice-overs by doctors reporting their results, as well as photographs of various scps that are contained by the foundation. I even have written testimony of staff and prisoners who were stationed there. However, technology has made hiding misdeeds much simpler. Pictures can be photoshopped, documents can be faked, etc. The media has also changed. Instead of their being one official narrative, information is now viewed and absorbed through partisan lenses. With different stations and papers taking sides based on tribal politics, it has become difficult to separate truth from opinion. On top of this, political world leaders declare this campaign as a hoax or "witch Hunt" of the fake news media to get ratings. Whistleblowers can easily be exposed and discredited, with them being subsequently eliminated or disappeared.

How can I prove that my evidence isn't fake?

Comment: Seems like a "write my story" to me. Perhaps I'm being too mean.

Comment: (1) Governments cannot engage in vast world-spanning conspiracies; governments change every few years and it is highly unlikely that the former opposition party will honor the unwritten agreements of their predecessors. (2) If you feel that the government of your country did something wrong the correct course of action is to vote for the opposition and volunteer to help with their campaign. (3) Most countries in this world have Constitutional Courts where you can bring a case against a law or other normative act put forth by the government.

Comment: What is the nature of your evidence?   How much do you expect me to reasonably doubt it (assuming I'm a bog-standard sceptic and disbelieving out of lack of proof, not malice intent to your conclusion)?   How did you procure this evidence and how can I be sure you're not running a reverse-cover story?

Comment: You do just like any other conspiracy theorist: set up a web site, enroll other theorists, maybe publish books or movies...  Of course you will, like all other conspiracy theoriests, be regarded as a complete nutcase by everyone who doesn't buy into your particular theory, but isn;t ridicule so much better than a bullet in the head?

Answer (score 3):

Given that you specified that you're trying to expose the SCP Foundation, I would say that you have to avoid trying to make your expose a matter of *revealing documentation* and instead make it more a matter of *providing a live demonstration*.

A painstakingly-prepared case made up of leaked files, witness statements, experimental test results, etc. can be dismissed as a hoax or as fake news, or simply argued against in bad faith.  If on the other hand you manage to free SCP-682 and accompany him down 5th Avenue in New York on a Wednesday morning, it will be much more difficult to dismiss the resulting carnage as a hoax.  (Please don't do this with SCP-096.)

Your own in-universe examples may vary, but essentially there is a practical line between *litigable* evidence and *crushing* evidence, and you need to get on the right side of that line.

Comment: On the other hand, if you did something like release 682 and use it as proof you were correct, you'd feel the sweet, sweet success of moral victory right up until you were beaten to death by outraged survivors.

Comment: Releasing SCP-682 would be one of the best arguments *for* the SCP foundation; "See, if we didn't exist, creatures like this would terrorize society"

Answer (score 1):

Theres no doubt about it, you're going to die for your actions.

create a private key, post it anonymously in major newsgroups. Send the key using alias email addresses to major news organizations, every single one.

Now, start posting the documents, encrypt them with that key. There'll be no way to tell who's actually corroborating with you, since it's publicly available.

Launch multiple servers in non descript locations. set jobs to periodically redistribute the documents to major news outlets everywhere using the same technique. In the case you're killed, these documents will continue to be distributed after your death.